# div is moving up and overlapping with navbar

Tags: css

In one of my web pages ,i have a div (with class name  **centered**) placed in center of the page, which contains some drop downs. Based on the selected values , it will show some check boxes.But whenever it is displaying check boxes , the div is moving up and overlapping with navbar in some screens.Can someone please fix this?

```
css for centered class is

.centered {
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 bottom:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform:-webkit-translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform:-moz-translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform:-ms-translate(-50%,-50%);
 width:400px;
 border:1 px solid black;
 padding:25px;
 margin:50px;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show a working example or fiddle?

Comment: You are required to provide an example of the problem here. The CSS alone is not an example.

Comment: we need to see : *(navbar css) + *the container that ("centered" class) is in + *your html container of this classes "to see if there is any conflict between them" + *screen image of your problem when you debug your website , here how to capture screen image if you dont know how : [click here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-pc/)  .....

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding. The div which class is centered should be fixed on the center. Looking at your code, you set `top:55%;` and `bottom:50%;` . It should be like this, you may try it.

```
.centered {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
transform: translate(-50 % , -50 % );
transform: -webkit - translate(-50 % , -50 % );
transform: -moz - translate(-50 % , -50 % );
transform: -ms - translate(-50 % , -50 % );
width: 400 px;
border: 1 px solid black;
padding: 25 px;
margin: 50 px;
}
```

Comment: top is 50% only... i have tried your css, its not working.

Comment: can you show a working fiddle? it is hard to imagine this thing without any example :)